# Arduino Error: "expected unqualified-id before 'else'"

Tags: arduino

I am receiving an "expected unqualified-id before 'else'" error on line 23, highlighted by **below, during compiling, which I am uncertain how to interpret its meaning. Thoughts on what it means?

---

```
void loop() {                                         
  if (cycleTally <= 3) {                               
     for (count = 0, cycleTally = 0; count<3 && cycleTally==3;count++,cycleTally++) {   
          digitalWrite(led, LOW);                          //LED is dim for 250 ms
          delay (timeBlockArrayShort[count]);              //count = 1 in the array, 250 ms
          digitalWrite(led, HIGH);                         //LED is bright for 250 ms
          delay (timeBlockArrayShort[count + 1]);          //count = 2 in the array, 250 ms
}
}
**else** {                                             //error location
if (cycleTally <= 6) {                            //
  for (count = 0, cycleTally = 4; count<3 && cycleTally==6;count++,cycleTally++) {
     digitalWrite(led, LOW);
     delay (timeBlockArrayLong[count]);
     digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
     delay (timeBlockArrayLong[count + 1]);
  }
  }
```

Comment: Is it exactly your code? It seems (I guess...) there is something wrong between "}" and "else" or an extra "{" or "}" before it. Where do you close loop() function?

Comment: For this kind of errors I would leave loop() empty then try to compile, add first if() with empty blocks then try to compile, add for() with empty block...and so on until I find offending block, then should be easier to see where error is (even line by line in case you're using "custom" macros).

Comment: yes it is... it is a partial of the code which contains the error. the first section up until the 'else' compiles. i just don't know what the error message is trying to tell me.

Answer (score 1):

You should develop your own style or discipline to format your code so that it is obvious how the brackets pair-up:

```
void loop() 
{                                         
  if (cycleTally <= 3)
  {                               
     for (count = 0, cycleTally = 0; count < 3 && cycleTally == count++,cycleTally++)              
      {   
         digitalWrite(led, LOW);                 //LED is dim for 250 ms
         delay (timeBlockArrayShort[count]);     //count = 1 in the array, 250 ms
         digitalWrite(led, HIGH);                //LED is bright for 250 ms
         delay (timeBlockArrayShort[count + 1]); //count = 2 in the array, 250 ms
      }  // end for

  } else {                 //error location ??
      if (cycleTally <= 6)
      {
           for (count = 0, cycleTally = 4; count<3 && cycleTally==6;count++,cycleTally++)
           {
              digitalWrite(led, LOW);
              delay (timeBlockArrayLong[count]);
              digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
              delay (timeBlockArrayLong[count + 1]);
           }  // end for
       }

   } ///<<<<< THIS WAS MISSING after formatting!!!
```

Thus, nice, clean code makes it obvious when a } or { is missing.